# How to update ajax when var attribute changes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a calendar-datepicker and a script, when I select a doctor from the list and click on the day of the calendar, the available time slots open in a separate div. The script works well, but if I choose another doctor while the time slot is open, the time slots don't update or disappear until I click on a calendar day. How can I change this script so that when choosing another doctor from the select option, the time slots disappear and are updated?

```
 <select class="form-select doctor_id doc" id="doctor" name="doctor" required>
                    <option selected disabled value="">Firs Select a Department</option>
                  </select>
```

```
<span id="date_field" ></span>
```

```
     $('#datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
   onSelect: function(dateText, inst) { 
   $('#date_time').val(dateText);
 var doctor_id = $(".doctor_id").val();
    $.ajax({url:'<?= base_url() ?>frontend/get_datetime',
                type: 'POST',
                data: {date: dateText, doctor_id: doctor_id},
                success: (function (data) {
                     $("#date_field").html(data);
                })
            })
            },showOtherMonths: true,
    selectOtherMonths: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can close the datepicker manually with the [hide](https://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#method-hide) function.

```
$('#doctor').on("click", function() {
  $('#datepicker').datepicker("hide");
});
```

Comment: Alternatively, you could destroy and rebuild the datepicker on a change of the select field. IT's depending on the rest of the code.

Comment: The rest of the code is php, which receives the post and date and doctor id method.

Comment: solved the problem by adding another ajax request to the handler with the function of changing the doctor